# AWS Code Deploy appspec isn't starting my server

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

So I'm using AWS Code deploy... Code makes it to the server just fine, I can see everything is where it needs to be. My appspec.yml looks like this:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: ./
    destination: /dmi
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 500
      runas: root
```

Pretty basic. The problem is CodeDeploy never seems to execute scripts/start_server.sh

That file just looks like this:

```
java -jar ../*.jar
```

If I ssh into that machine and just manually run ./scripts/start_server.sh it runs fine. So why isn't code deploy executing start_server.sh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my `scripts/start_server.sh` script I found I had to redirect `stdin` and `stdout` *and* background the task:

```
/var/myservice/scripts/run > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &
```

otherwise launch seemed to hang.